# Mysql Trigger error

Tags: mysql, select, insert, triggers

1.I m using mysql 5.2.2 version

2.I create table in my test database

```
CREATE TABLE account (acct_num INT, amount DECIMAL(10,2));
```

3.I also Create trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON account
FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount;
```

4.I insert data into account table

```
INSERT INTO account VALUES(137,14.98),(141,1937.50),(97,-100.00);
```

5.After then when i use following command for show data

```
SELECT @sum AS 'Total amount inserted';
```

6.I can't find data what is problem for that or any mistake in this code?

```
Total amount inserted
 NULL
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `@sum` prior to inserting values.  For example:

```
SET @sum := 0;
INSERT INTO account VALUES(137,14.98),(141,1937.50),(97,-100.00);
SELECT @sum AS 'Total amount inserted';
+-----------------------+
| Total amount inserted |
+-----------------------+
|               1852.48 |
+-----------------------+
```